# How to fetch a row with PDO

Tags: php, pdo

I'm trying not to get frustrated, but I've recently learned that `mysql_*` is deprecated in PHP. I've decided that I would learn how to use PDO.

I've just been looking at it this afternoon, and connecting to the database using it was easy, but then I wanted to fetch a row with it and save the row as an array indexed by the column names (the same way as the function `mysql_fetch_array` did). I can't figure it out to save my life.

I'll post my code to clarify, and I'm sure it is something simple (all programming errors are always simple), but I am definitely doing something wrong.

```
// Connect to the database
$host    = $_PARAM["DatabaseServer"];
$db        = $_PARAM["MainDatabase"];
$dbuser    = $_PARAM["DatabaseUser"];
$dbpass    = $_PARAM["DatabasePass"];
try
{
    $Database = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db", $dbuser, $dbpass);
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    echo "There was an unexpected error. Please try again, or contact us with concerns";
}

$stmt = $Database->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=?");
$stmt->execute(array($sUserCook));
$row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo $row["username"];
```

Comment: Can you see the syntax highlighting here? Did you get an error message? If not, did you enable error_reporting?

Comment: The `prepare()` line here has some missing quotes, but you probably knew that.

Comment: programming is frustrating when you don't get error messages to help guide you. you need to configure php to show you errors.

Comment: You guys are right, the error was there telling me I had a missing quote, but I couldn't find it anywhere. Thank you for finding it for me. I'm telling you, it's always the simplest things that get you.

Answer (score 20):

`fetchAll` does what it says: it fetches all results for a query. Since it fetches a lot of results, you'll get an indexed array.

`fetch` does what you might be looking for if you want only one row: it fetches one result for a query. If you're converting `mysql_*` code to PDO, the quickest way would be to just use this method instead of `mysql_fetch_assoc`.

If you're still going with `fetchAll`: your code would probably just look like this:

```
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    echo $row['username'];
}
```

Like I said, if you're just converting legacy code to PDO code, it might be easier to just change all queries to prepared statements and replace the following:

- `mysql_fetch_assoc($result)`
  -> `$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`
- `mysql_num_rows($result)`
  -> `$stmt->rowCount()`
- `while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {}`
  -> `foreach ($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row) {}`

Comment: That makes sense, I appreciate your quick response and I will use your advice. I changed the code and it is not giving me the error Fatal error: Call to undefined method Database::prepare() in \xxxx.php on line. Why is it telling me it is undefined? Thank you

Comment: I'm guessing that your "Database" class isn't a PDO object, which is why you can't prepare() on it.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

You will get the first query result.