# How to fetch single row data from php?

Tags: php

```
  for ($i=$start; $i<$start+$scale && $i < $total_record; $i++)        

  {
   $sql = "select * from memo where num = ?";
   $stmh = $pdo->prepare($sql);
  //mysql_data_seek($result, $i);       
  $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);   
      $sql2 = "select * from phptest.memo order by num desc";
      $stmh2 = $pdo->query($sql2);
      $stmh2->execute();
      //$row = $stmh2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
      $row = $stmh->fetchColumn($i-1);


  $memo_id      = $row['id'];
  $memo_num     = $row['num'];
  $memo_date    = $row['regist_day'];
  $memo_nick    = $row['nick'];
  $memo_content = $row['content'];
```

Hi guys i want fetch single row data by using PDO method instead of `$row = $stmh2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` like `mysqli_data_seek($result,$i);`. What should i do?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14035108/how-to-fetch-row-with-pdo/14035132#14035132

Comment: simply $stmh2->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)

Comment: I want to know how to convert mysql_data_seek($result,$i) to PDO CODE

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql2 = "select * from phptest.memo order by num desc";
$stmh2 = $pdo->query($sql2);
$stmh2->execute();
while($r = $stmh2->fetch()) {$row[] = $r;}
```

Now $row[$i] should be getting you the same results as mysqli_data_seek($result,$i) would have.
IE: $row[0] would return the first row.

Comment: $row[$i] is local variable how can i use it?